# How do you aggregate data from references in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, nosql

```
User{
      '_id' : ObjectId(..),
      'Friends': [{_id : ref1},{id : ref2}]
      'Posts' : [{'popularity' :103,...}, {'popularity' : 86,...}
}
```

And each of the references linked to another users id in Friends.
What's the fastest way to get the most popular posts out of all of a users friends?
Maybe just the top 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB allows flexible schema design to make up for not having joins.  So I assume in this schema the relationship is "two-way" (i.e. if I'm your friend then you're in my friends array and I'm in your friends array?)

In that case you can do the following aggregation query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match : { "Friends._id": <my _id> } },
    {$unwind : "$Posts" },
    {$sort :  { "Posts.popularity" : -1 },
    {$limit : 20 }
] )
```

Basically, filter for all users who have me in their friends array, unwind their posts array, sort to get posts with highest popularity first and limit to top 20.

If you don't have an index on "Friends._id" this will not be a fast query.

Comment: This is it. I don't believe I added an index on Friends._id. Would that be as simple as using ensureindex?

Comment: yes, but remember it's a blocking operation unless you use "background: true" option.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/